# Bulk creation of VM guests in VMware

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

Is it possible to create a number of windows VMs from a template e.g. 15. I was going to create one VM without IP address etc and just clone it 15 times then configure the ip addresses, is there an easier quicker method.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. It's a totally valid question. The downvotes do express the fact that this is a basic VMware feature and shows no research effort, though.

Comment: Let me google this for you: https://www.google.ch/#q=vmware+template

Comment: @mfinni: There's only one close vote yet as far as I can see, and that's "unclear what you're asking". If you refer to the downvote: The question does not show any research effort, as my google search for "vmware template" reveals hundreds of hits for exactly this question...

Comment: Yup, agree on the downvotes.

Comment: vCenter Orchestrator.  That's how I do it, anyway.

Comment: And another close vote. sorry, but read the documentation and learn the basics before asking on a place where beginner questions are not welcome as per site rules.

Comment: Bulk creation of VM's is not basic VMware admin, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's exactly what templates are for. Don't do this via cloning a VM 15 times- make a new VM (or clone one), convert that into a template, and then create the VMs from the template.

You could even script it with vSphere PowerCLI and assign the IPs and machine names that way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's called template and you can clone it.

Comment: I am aware of that as I already mentioned in the question the basic method of using templates, instead of jumping quickly to answer please read the question, using v Center Orchestrator, as mentioned by Tom is the correct way to bulk create vm's.

Comment: Well, I basically said the same as @mfinni..  and his answer got 2 votes + a "right answer"... ?

Comment: He's incorrect, how is bulk creation a basic feature of vmware, when its not available until you install an additional feature.

Comment: I wouldn't call creating 15 VM's "bulk creation". Also, you still accepted @mfinni's answer.

Comment: he mentioned that you can script this, which again, not basic, however is useful. I'll leave the answer with Tom.

Comment: OK, I removed the "VMware Basics". Better? Also, you should ask @Tom to provide his comment as an answer and then accept this.